# How to set the active control of a TabPage dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am not asking how to set the active control of a Form (I know how to do it). I have 2 `TabPage`s within a `TabControl` and I would like that whenever a certain `TabPage` is selected, a certain `TabPage`'s control becomes the active control of the `SelectedTab`.

I have tried something like that:

```
if (searcher_tabControl.SelectedIndex == 0)
    this.ActiveControl = findWhat_find_textBox;
else//SelectedIndex == 1
    this.ActiveControl = findWhat_replace_textBox;
```

This of course works now, but if I wanted to change the design of my program/`TabControl`, I should modify this control flow (if I remember).

Do you know a better approach to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in the constructor of the Form with the TabControl:

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) =>
    ActiveControl = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                               .SingleOrDefault(x => x.TabIndex == 0);
```

Every time you switch tabs, it'll select the control (if any) with a `TabIndex` of 0.

You'll have to make sure the control you want to set as "active" has a `TabIndex` of 0 in the tab page. If you forget to set one to 0, then no control will be set as "active" (and no exception will be thrown either).

---

> How do you call this way of adding and event handler? I've never seen the usage of `=>` operator in C#.

That's an inline method. If you compare it to the normal way you setup an event method, the `s` is your `object sender`, the `e` is your `EventArgs e`, and the statement after the lambda operator `=>` is the code to execute for that event. If you wanted to execute multiple lines of code, you'd surround them in curly braces:

```
... += (s, e) => { something(); somethingElse(); };
```

Alternatively, since we're not actually doing anything with the parameters, you could also say:

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += delegate
{
    ActiveControl = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                               .SingleOrDefault(x => x.TabIndex == 0);
};
```

Any method you use, these or the way you're used to, the end result is the same. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what control is intended to be on each tabpage so my example focuses on the control with the first tabindex to be the active one.Having said that subscribe to the Selected event on the tabControl and place this code:

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = e.TabPage.Controls.OfType<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex).First();
}
```